# Working with Classes in vb6 with user selected fields

Tags: class, vb6

I found out how to create the properties of the class, like this:

```
  private m_Name as string

  public property get Name() as string
    Name = m_Name
  end sub
  public property let Name(sval as string)
    m_name = sval
  end sub
```

The user will create a document and choose some `fields` (Name, Birthday, Phone....) inside this document, as I can't know exactly which fields will be chosen by the user, I thought create a class would be the best option.

After I create the class like above, how may I make a loop through this class to check which fields has been chosen by the user?

Any better option for my situation, please, let me know...

Comment: How you know, which fields are choosen by user? By just changing their values? Then create another set on class variables (and such variables are actually not global - your comment is incorrect), like "Private m_Name_Changed as boolean" and assign them True in "Property Let" method. Alternatively - if choosing fields means assigning them non-empty values - you can just check, which fields are not empty.

Comment: @Arvo The fields means, values like (name, phone, adress etc...). It's actually fields from the table, and the user wants the value of these fields on the document... So, When the user choose a field it will appear like this "<Name>" on the document, then I'll check if there is something like "<Name>" and make a replace with the value of the field name, using a recordset, you know ?

Comment: Hmm, I refuse to understand, how your class is related to your problem? If you have recordset, then you can scan over recodset fields collection and check, does requested field exists or not - and if it exists, read and assign value from recordset. No other classes are required for this task.

Comment: @Arvo I have 22 possible `fields` to be choosen by the user. I can't say wich fields or how many of these fields will be picked up. So, What I need to know is have a list with the possibilities and check wich of them has been choosen, you know ? Or your suggestion is to create a new table with the possibilities then loop through the recordset to check if it ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the user will add tags or something to something like a document (e.g. `[Name]`) and you want to know how to map your class members to these tags.  To do this, you dont really want to loop thru the class members, but the document tags to find out what is needed.  When you find a "tag", submit it to your class to fill in the blank.

Part 1 is a parser to find the tags...my VB6 is very rusty, so pseudocode for this:

```
 Const TagStart = "["            ' "$[" is better as it is not likely to appear
 Const TagStop = "]"             ' "]$"  "    "   "

 ' make this a loop looking for tags
 i = Instr(docScript, TagStart)
 j = Instr(docScript, TagStop)
 thisTag = Mid(docScript, TagStart, TagEnd )
 ' not correct, but the idea is to get the text WITH the Start and Stop markers
 ' like [Name] or [Address]

 ' get the translation...see below
 docText = MyClass.Vocab(thisTag)

 ' put it back
 Mid(docScript, TagStart, TagEnd) = docText
```

It is actually better to look for each possible legal tag (ie `Instr(docScript, "[Name]")`) which are stored in an array but you may have to do that in 2 loops to allow that a given tag could be requested more than once.

Part 2 supply the replacement text from MyClass:

```
 Friend Function Vocab(tag as string) As String
     Dim Ret as string

     Select Case tag
          Case "$[NAME]$"
              ret = "Name:  " & m_Name 
              ' if the caption is part of the "script" then just:
              'ret = m_Name

          Case "$[ADDRESS]$"
              ret = "Address:  " & m_Addr

          ' if not found, return the tag so you can add new Vocab items
          ' or user can fix typos like '[NMAR]'
          Case Else
              ret = tag

          ...
      End Select
      Return Ret
  End Function
```

The parsing routines in Part 1 could also be a method in your class to process the document "script" which calls a private Vocab.

**Edit**

a fraction of a 'script' might look like this:
   `Customer's Name:| $[CUST_FNAME]$ $[CUST_LNAME]$`  (ignore the pipe (|) it was a table cell marker)

The parser looks thru the string to find "$[", when it does, it isolates the related tag `$[CUST_FNAME]$`.   If you have a large number, the first part (CUST) can be used as a router to send it to the correct class.  Next, call the method to get the translation:

```
  newText = Cust.Vocab(thisTag)
```

Cust Class just looks at the tag and returns "Bob" or whatever and the parsing loop replaces the tag with the data:
    `Customer's Name:| Bob $[CUST_LNAME]$`

Then just continue until all the tags have been replaced.

With "just" 22 vocab items, you could create a dedicated class for it:

```
   Vocab.Translate(tag ...) as string

        Case "$[CUST_FNAME]$"
            return Cust.FirstName
```

...or

Are you trying to work out a way to do this via a DOC object from office?  The above is more of from the ground up document composition type thing.  For office I'd think you just need some sort of collection of replacement text.

HTH

Comment: I don't get it =x. I'll create a document(.PDF or .DOC) and it will have a text with some `tags` like `Hi Mr. <Name> today <date>, we from <FirmName> are glad to be celebrating with your birthday.`. I thought to create a `struct` Like `Private Type T_Fields`. What do you think?

Comment: thats exactly where the above came from - search something and replace placeholder tags with data.  I originally used "<>" yrs ago, but too many things allow HTML like links, so I changed to something 'not found in nature' ("$[xxx]$").  I've used it (in VB6) for 6 page insurance docs to convert a "script" to a legal doc.  if it is a small Vocabulary you could use a collection type thing, mine had nearly 1000 tags (tags were more complex 'CUST_FNAME', 'PLAN_TYPENAME' and had to be "routed" to the right class to get the answer.  I dunno how I would use `T_Fields` to any benefit.

Comment: Sorry for my dumbish, but I still not getting how to use it =s

Comment: The top part looks for tags in the "script" which would be a string which would be part or all of a document. Then `docText = MyClass.Vocab(thisTag)' calls the second block.  The 'Vocab' sees "<Name>" and returns "Mr John Smith", which is inserted into the string where <Name> used to be.  It SEEMS like it would be better to have a 'script' as a separate string, swap out the text, THEN make the PDF/DOc so that line wrap etc works as intended.  The Vocab can include mark up like RPT_NEWLINE, RPT_NEWPAGE etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to know which fields (out of a number of existing fields) user used/initialized?

I see several ways to do it:
1) If your variables do not have default values and must have a non-empty/non-zero values, then you can simply check if a variable is empty or zero. If it is, it hasn't been initialized.

```
If m_name = "" Then MsgBox "Variable is not initialized"
```

2) for each field you have, create a boolean `fieldName_Initialized` so for each field, you would have something like this:

```
  private m_Name as string
  private m_name_Initialized as Boolean

  public property get Name() as string
    Name = m_Name
  end sub
  public property let Name(sval as string)
    m_name = sval
    m_name_Initialized = True
  end sub
```

3) you could have a list and add variable names to the list as they become initialized:
Make sure to add `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` to your References for Dictionary to work.

```
  Dim initialized As Dictionary
  Set initialized  = New Dictionary

  private m_Name as string
  private m_name_Initialized as Boolean

  public property get Name() as string
    Name = m_Name
  end sub
  public property let Name(sval as string)
    m_name = sval
    initialized.Add "m_name", True
  end sub
```

Then, to check if the var has been initialized:

```
If initialized.Exists("m_name") Then 
    ' Var is initialized
```

4) similar to #3, except use an array of booleans. Tie specific var to a specific index, like `m_name` is index 0. This way you skip the hassle of controlling variable names (adds to maintenance cause as far as I know you can't get the name of the variable)

Personally, #1 is the most simple, but may not be possible in a certain situations. If #1 does not apply, I would personally pick #2, unless someone can figure out how to get a string representation of a variable name from the variable itself, then #3 is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is a kind of Nullable-behaviour. Yes you can do this ins VB6 with the datatype Variant. Then you can use the function "IsEmpty()" to check if a property was already set or not.
a little code-example:

```
Option Explicit  
Private m_Vars()  
'0 : Name
'1 : Birthday
'2 : Phone
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim m_Vars(0 To 2)
End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = m_Vars(0)
End Property
Public Property Let Name(RHS As String)
    m_Vars(0) = RHS
End Property

Public Property Get Birthday() As Date
    Birthday = m_Vars(1)
End Property
Public Property Let Birthday(RHS As Date)
    m_Vars(1) = RHS
End Property

Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(m_Vars)
        Dim v: v = m_Vars(i)
        If IsEmpty(v) Then
            MsgBox "is empty"
        Else
            MsgBox v
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user has a form that they do something to create their document, why not use simple checkbox controls, one for each possible field? If you want to use a loop to check for selected fields make the checkboxes a control array and loop though the array. You can assign the field name to the `Tag` property, then if the checkbox is checked add the field to an array.

[image: checkboxes]